# Convert a cell of strings to a matrix of numbers

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, numbers, cells

I'm trying to convert a cell of numbers of different lengths to a matrix of numbers. I'm new to Matlab cells. I apologize in advance if this question sucks. I've done my homework, this is my last resort.

`x` is my cell of strings. I want these strings converted to numbers. Is there a way to convert the cell into a matrix without brute force iteration?

I've tried `cell2mat` but Matlab freaks out. I've tried `str2num` but Matlab freaks out. I've googled "converting a cell of strings to a matrix of numbers", but nothing comes up.

Here's the cell:

```
>>x 

x = 
'0'
'850'
'10483'
'16039'
'25670'
'31242'
'37009'
'41023'
'46798'
'51881'
'61491'
'67181'
'72941'
'76163'
'85759'
'96654'
'102439'
'104615'
'114224'

>>class(x)

ans =

cell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
x = {'1';'12';'3.14'};
y = str2double(x)
```

which returns

```
y = 

    1.000000000000000
   12.000000000000000
    3.140000000000000
```

The reason that `mat2cell` didn't work is because your numeric strings are of different lengths. And `str2num` doesn't even permit cell inputs. You might also read the help and doc for [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) for other reasons why `str2double` is better anyways.